# Продвижение Андроид-приложения

Tags: android, google-play, продвижение, раскрутка

Написал своё первое приложение, это секундомер с таймером. Теперь хочу выложить его в Play Market и даже не знаю, что дальше. Основа — платная версия, но думаю сделать ещё урезанную бесплатную.

В общем, как я понял, это очень ответственный шаг (очень часто приходится видеть плохие приложения чуть ли не в топе, а хорошие и интересные приложения всего с 10—50 загрузками). Но вот не знаю, что делать в первую очередь? Где выкладывать обзоры? Стоит ли вкладывать деньги в продвижение (изначально решил продвигать бесплатно)? Приложение имеет и английскую версию, и если с русскоязычной ещё более-менее понятно, то с английской полный ноль.

Comment: Основываясь на собственном опыте и опыте компаний, в которых удалось поработать, могу сказать, что большинство пользователей предпочитают бесплатную версию с IAP для разблокирования отдельных возможностей, нежели отдельно платную полнофункциональную версию и отдельно бесплатную лайт.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и раскрутке не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Без лайт версии - не будет работать
2. Запостите лайт версию в разные аппсторы (сейчас их много). Навскидку: Amazon, Samsung Apps, GetJar, Appoke и проч.
3. Русскую версию выложите на 4PDA
4. Прочтите книгу про [маркетинг Android апп](http://www.amazon.com/Android-Apps-Marketing-Secrets-Biz-Tech/dp/0789746336)
5. Не ленитесь отвечать на сообщения юзеров

Answer (score 4):

Секундомер-таймер платный? Не стоит. Сейчас не 2008 год, когда не было подобных приложений. Это все было раньше. Сейчас это все не работает. Большая конкуренция - большие компании - много хороших приложений + смотря на какой рынок вы ориентируетесь. На русский точно не стоит надеяться особо с платной версией. Выше Вам уже посоветовали что можно начать делать, согласен, добавлю только что еще можно выложить в SlideMe локализованную на анг язык версию и можно попробовать добавить AdMob.

Кроме этого, если Вы этого не делали, то попробуйте: проанализируйте конкурентов вашего приложения и добавьте что-то особенное в свой апп. Если вкратце, то вот какой он должен быть примерно:
 - Должна быть симпатичная графика и UI
 - Как можно меньше багов и особенно крашей
 - Видео работы приложения
 - Красивые скриншоты
 - Особенность который нет у конкурентов
 - Можно сделать сайт/блог о приложении и добавить ссылку везде на этот сайт

И еще отличным советом будет методика ребят из 37signals(авторов книги Rework): делайте приложение которым вы сами будете пользоваться. Отсюда будет очень много полезного, ведь вы сразу поймете свою аудитории и возможные косяки или сильные стороны своего приложения.

Я думаю сейчас, чтобы приложение было более-менее популярным важна идея + качественная реализация + платное продвижение в спец. сайты(хотя бы в начале).

Comment: Да, я это всё прекрасно понимаю. Я и сам не стал бы просить деньги за какое нибудь примитивное приложение. И пришёл к решению делать именно секундомер, когда увидел что в среди платных конкуренция очень низкая и они набирают примерно 3000 загрузок за 2-3 месяца (столько мне и нужно). Моё приложение уже отличается от конкурентов, так что деньги есть за что просить )
Ну прямо в топе шлака нет. Но вот около топа, на высоких позициях - вполне. Особенно в каких нибудь не популярных категориях.
Всё равно спасибо за совет =)

Answer (score 1):

- маркеты AppBrain, AndroidPit
- Опубликуйте статью на Хабре: 100500 установок, заодно много ценных замечаний. Таких тестеров еще поискать
- ну и по поводу плтных установок, тоже верно. Для Android можно вот этими ребятами пользоваться http://advertmobile.net/